# Highlight the specific area of the image using .maphilight()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap, maphilight

I want to `highlight` the specific area of the image tag on `keyPress` Event. While using `.maphilight()` method from the [maphilight jQuery plugin](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/), it is working only on `mouseover` on the area.

I am using chart image and which contain the no.of series points with area tag.

when click the navigation key focus is move to one point to another point and focused point will need to highlight.

How to use .maphilight() method to highlight the specific area of image on "KeyPress"

I would appreciate your code and suggestions.

Thanks,

Bharathi.

Comment: Please show the code you currently have.

Comment: $('imageid').maphilight(); this is work only on the mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    $('#idOfAreaToHighlight').mouseover();
});
```

This will trigger when any key is pressed. If you need to limit it to a specific key you can add an if statement to check event.keyCode.

Comment: Could you please explain with details? and why we use the below code?$('#idOfAreaToHighlight').mouseover();

Comment: I try the above code.. but i something miss or not use properly. So please explain me with detail

Comment: @user2990596 That's where you specify the ID of the area you want to highlight on the keypress. If you edit your question to include your HTML, I'll be able to give you a more complete answer.